# Meaning of "bruised Trump"

Tags: phrase-meaning

I have read in the news recently the expression"bruised Trump". Can you paraphrase it for me

Comment: It would help if you provided a link and example sentence (cite it if it is a sentence from another source.). Also, do you know what “bruised” means literally, and just are trying to understand the figurative meaning?

Comment: Look up "bruised ego".

Comment: This needs context.  Voting to place on hold as unclear.  It can be reopened if you edit with more details.

Answer (score 3):

Think of talking about Trump as (metaphorically) being engaged in a fight (presumably with the Congress or its Democrats).  Some opponent of his had landed an effective punch, which had ‘bruised’ him.

Answer (score 1):

Since no one else has chimed in on this point, "bruised ego" refers to having something causing one's sense of self worth (their "ego") to be somehow reduced.  (See, for example, [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/bruise-sb-s-ego).)

It's hard to say for sure (lacking any context) but it's likely the the user of the term "bruised Trump" considers "Trump" to be a synonym for "ego", and hence is saying "bruised ego".

Ie, if someone says "Fred seems to have a bruised Trump" then they're likely saying that Fred's *ego* has been injured.

Answer (score 0):

to **bruise**  [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/23910?rskey=rpX5ik&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid) figurative sense

> fig. Of a person's pride, ego, feelings, etc.: hurt, wounded; injured
>   emotionally.

As in:

*X was bruised after attending multiple adversarial events.*